# Picking random integers $a_i$ until the $\gcd(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ is 1

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

When we say "pick a random integer", the integers are in the range $[1, N]$.

**Problem:**

Consider the following instructions:

> Pick a random integer.
>
> Find the greatest common divisor of all the integers which have been picked so far.
>
> If the greatest common divisor is not 1, go back to the first step to pick a random integer.

When this process ends, let $X$ be the total number of integers you have picked. I would like to find $E(X)$ in terms of $N$.

Example of this process: (where $N=4$)

1. I picked the random integer, 2.
2. $\gcd(2)=2$
3. I picked another random integer, 4.
4. $\gcd(2, 4) = 2$
5. I picked another random integer, 2.
6. $\gcd(2, 4, 2) = 2$
7. I picked another random integer, 3.
8. $\gcd(2, 4, 2, 3) = 1$

In total, I picked $X=4$ integers, $2, 4, 2, 3$.

**My ideas:**

A easy upper bound can be shown to be $N$, which is the expected number of numbers to be chosen before getting a 1.

Let $M(g, N)$ be the expected number of integers I will need after getting $g$ as the greatest common divisor of the integers so far.

We have $E(X)=1+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^NM(g, N)}{N}$.

**Small cases:**

$N=1\rightarrow E(X)=1$

$N=2\rightarrow E(X)=2$

Comment: This seems to be tied to the distribution of primes, which means that a nice, self-contained, concrete answer will be difficult, to say the least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(not an answer, but still probably worth a look)*

I'll get you a better upper bound.

What is the probability that our gcd is divisible by two? It is $1\over2$ after the first step, $1\over4$ after the second, and so on. The probability of being divisible by 3, likewise, behaves as ${1\over3^n}$; then goes 5 and the rest of primes. What is the probability of gcd being divisible by *anything at all* except 1? Obviously, no more than the sum of the above (actually, less than that, because they overlap): ${1\over4}+{1\over9}+{1\over25}...$ after step 2, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty{1\over p_i^3}$ after step 3, and so on. Thus the expected number of steps would be bounded from above with $1+1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty{1\over p_i^2}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty{1\over p_i^3}+\dots = 2+\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty{1\over p_i(p_i-1)} < 2+\sum\limits_{i=2}^\infty{1\over i(i-1)}=3$.

Note that the obtained bound is independent of $N$.

Comment: Sounds like a good enough answer to show that the bound is finite.

Comment: Finite and quite small, I'd say.